# How do I insert an onclick to this jquery to fetch details of the images from json(image also got from json)

Tags: jquery, json

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonURL = "search.json";
    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json)
    {
         var imgList= "";
         $.each(json.Images, function () {
            imgList += '<li><img src= "' + this.image + '"></li>';
         });});
```

Above is the script which fetches the images from json.

Comment: 1- Please provide as much information as you can in your questions in order to we be able to help you. can you at least add the data structure of your `json` file? 2- have you tried anything? any codes? 3- you want to add the `onclick` event to what object? 4- do you want to add this event to objects dynamically added to your document?

Comment: {"Items":[{"id":"s", "name":"screw", "location":"A1", "quantity":12, "group":"0","image":"screw.jpg"},
{"id":"1", "name":"image1", "location":"A1", "quantity":12, "group":"0","image":"screw1.jpg"},
{"id":"2", "name":"image2", "location":"B4", "quantity":1, "group":"2","image":"screw2.jpg"},
{"id":"3", "name":"image3", "location":"Z2", "quantity":100, "group":"0","image":"screw3.jpg"},
{"id":"4", "name":"image4", "location":"C3", "quantity":19, "group":"0","image":"screw4.jpg"},]}

Comment: I got the images from this json. I want to get the name, location and quantity when i click on a particular image. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you have some button or ui element on which you want to attach the onclick event. Like:

```
<div id="target">
  Click here
</div>
```

In jquery, you need to give a function to the click handler of a ui-element.
You do it like :

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  alert( "Handler for .click() called." );
});
```

If you see , in `$("#target").click` function you passed a `function`. In your case, this should be your function that fetches the images. This should be easy now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all, you have two errors in you code.

in this line

`$.each(json.Images, function () {`

you do not have any object named *Images* in your `json` file, instead you have *Items*

and also in your `json` file there is a *,(comma)* in the end of the list which is causing an error and your `$.getJSON` will not parse the data.

so, after solving these issues, I think the easiest way is to use **custom data attribute**

assuming that you have an `HTML` element named `myList` the code will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var jsonURL = "search.json";

    $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(json){
        var imgList = '';

        $.each(json.Items, function(){
            imgList += '<li><img id="img'+this.id+'" src="'+this.image+'" data-name="'+this.name+'" data-location="'+this.location+'" data-quantity="'+this.quantity+'"></li>';
        });

        $("#myList").html(imgList);

        $("#myList li img").on('click', function(){
            var  myData = " name: "+$(this).data("name")+"\n location: "+$(this).data("location")+"\n quantity: "+$(this).data("quantity");
            console.log(myData);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry for the late reply. Thanks so much EhsanT for the correction and your codes. I appreciate it a lot